# Count of 3-digit numbers

Tags: permutations

> How many different three digit numbers can be formed with the digit $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$ none of the digit being repeated in any of the numbers so formed? $120/1200/180/270$

My attempt: $8*7*6=336$, but it's not an option. I wish somebody could help.

Comment: Don't beg for help.

Comment: Your interpretation/answer seem like the right ones.

Comment: I got 336 when checking with a computer. Are you sure you (and we) understand the question right?.